# Instance A = Instance B, what exactly does this do?

Tags: java, object, instance

What is happening when this code declares course2 = course1; Because what happens after that I can't make sense of. If I comment out course2 = course1; I get Programming Fundamentals twice.

```
public Course(int courseID, String courseName) {
    ID = courseID;
    name = courseName;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String newName) {
    name = newName;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Course course1 = new Course(2531, "Programming Fundamentals");
    Course course2 = new Course(1285, "Algorithms and Analysis");

    System.out.println(course1.getName());

    course2 = course1;
    course2.setName("PF");
    System.out.println(course1.getName());
}
```

This outputs as: 

Programming Fundamentals

PF

Comment: I know this should be obvious, but I don't understand the logic here.

Comment: It sets the references equal. What part of this confuses you exactly?

Comment: Here `course2` is pointing to same memory location as `course1` after eavluating `course2 = course1` so changing value by either `course1` or `course2` will reflect same memory location. This is Java 101 concepts.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction Boris... Why does it confuse me, well, we get to polymorphism and I'm thinking: I must have missed something basic here, not to mention it was in the mid-semester exam. It was taught back in week two, the tutor used rectangles to explain it, but her notes are rubbish and her lectures worse; it's confusing. So, I was simply trying to make it perfectly clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`course1` is a variable, it reference an object, let's say object1.

`course2` is another variable, it reference another object, let's say object2.

When you call `course2 = course1`, you make them reference the same object --`object1`.

Comment: Thanks, nice and simple. I didn't need a complex answer.

Comment: @NWoods See this about [what is an object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/object.html) and [what is variable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
course2 = course1;
```

changes the value of `course2` to be a reference to the same object referenced by `course1` (the object created by the statement `new Course(2531, "Programming Fundamentals")`).

Therefore both `course1` and `course2` now reference the same object, so `course2.setName("PF")` has the same behavior as `course1.setName("PF")`. Hence the second `System.out.println(course1.getName())` prints `"PF"`.

If you comment out the `course2 = course1;` assignment, `course2` references a different object, so `course2.setName("PF")` doesn't affect the object referenced by `course1`. Hence the second `System.out.println(course1.getName())` still prints `"Programming Fundamentals"`.

Comment: Thanks, fundamentals I know. But I always miss the basics and it doesn't hurt to ask.

Answer (score 0):

`course1` and `course2` are references to objects of the class `Course`.
With `course2 = course1` you change the object `course2` points to to the same one as `course1`. So you access the same object after that with both `course1`and `course2`.